# »Die Meinung ändern« und »sich darüber schlüssig werden«

Tags: word-usage, difference, phrase

> Ich habe die Meinung geändert, mit meiner Freundin zum Disko zu
>   fahren.
>
> Ich bin mir darüber schlüssig geworden, mit meiner Freundin zum Disko
>   zu fahren.

Kann man sie austauschbar benutzen und haben sie dieselbe Bedeutung?

Comment: Beide sind in meinen Augen mindestens holprig. »Ich habe meine Meinung **darüber** geändert, **ob ich** mit meiner Freundin zur Disko fahre« und »Ich bin mir darüber schlüssig geworden, **ob** ich [wie eben]«. Ich glaube nicht, dass hier Infinitivkonstruktionen möglich sind. Außerdem ist die Bedeutung eine andere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Bedeutungen unterscheiden sich. Deutlich. Und dementsprechend sind die beiden auch nicht austauschbar.

> Ich habe meine Meinung darüber geändert, ob ich mit meiner Freundin zur Disko fahre.

Es gibt zwei Möglichkeiten, diesen Satz zu verstehen. Entweder, der Sprecher war vorher dagegen, mit seiner Freundin zur Disko zu fahren. Dann wissen wir jetzt, dass er dafür ist. Auch das Gegenteil ist möglich. Zum Beispiel hätte Angela Merkel 2010, nach der Katastrophe in Fukushima der Presse sagen können:

> Ich habe meine Meinung zur Kernenergie geändert.

Denn sie war vor dem Unglück pro-Kernenergie eingestellt, was sich in ihren politischen Entscheidungen äußerte; nach dem Unglück aber kontra-Kernenergie (ebenfalls durch politische Entscheidungen gedeckt).

> Ich bin mir darüber schlüssig geworden, ob ich mit meiner Freundin zur Disko fahre.

Dieser Satz lässt immer noch offen, ob der Sprecher (oder die Sprecherin) nun mit seiner (oder ihrer) Freundin zur Disko fahren will, oder nicht. Der Unterschied zum vorherigen besteht in des Satzes Beziehung zur Vergangenheit: Früher hat der Sprecher überhaupt nicht gewusst, ob er in die Disko gehen möchte oder nicht. Es war früher keine Meinung da, nun ist eine da.

Als Beispiel, stelle dir jemanden vor, der sich für zwei verschiedene Stellen bei zwei verschiedenen Firmen beworben hat. Er hat zwei Zusagen zu sehr gut vergleichbaren Konditionen (Urlaub, Gehalt, etc) bekommen. Nun muss er sich für eine entscheiden. Nach einer Woche des Lamentierens könnte ein Freund abends in der Kneipe fragen:

> Bist du dir schon darüber schlüssig geworden, welchen Job du annehmen möchtest?

Und die Antwort könnte lauten:

> Ja, heute Nachmittag habe ich mich für die Großklotz-Baugesellschaft entschieden.

---

Kurz gefasst könnte man sagen, dass *schlüssig werden* wie *entscheiden*, *Meinung ändern* aber wie *umentscheiden* funktioniert.